# Parsing a dynamically defined nested map

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a JSON object that is dynamically defined.

```
{
   "lvars": {
      "task1": {
          "assigned" : true,
          "params": {//any key value maps here}, {//any key value maps}
        },
      "task2": {
          "assigned" : false,
          "params": {//any key value maps here}, {//any key value maps}
      ....
   },
   "mvars": {
          "Id": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": ""
        },
   }
}
```

Now in java when I am deserializing it into code it becomes somewhat like this,

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>>> m = ObjectMapper
            .fromJson(getValues(), new TypeReference<>() {});
```

In this case "lvars" and "mvars" are fixed keys and evrything else is variable. How can I avoid the nested map of maps declaration in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
Map<String,Object> data = ObjectMapper.fromJson(getValues(), new TypeReference<>() {});

    Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Object>>> dynamic_map_0 = (Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>) data.get("lvars");
    Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Object>>> dynamic_map_1 = (Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>) data.get("mvars");
```

or simpler:

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputAsString);
    JSONObject dynamic0 = obj.getJSONObject("lvars");
    JSONObject dynamic1 = obj.getJSONObject("mvars");
```

Comment: Ah yes, JSONObject is better than creating your own class!

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class called `NestedMap` which is a data structure that contains references to other NestedMap objects, like so:

```
class NestedMap<K, Object> {
    Map<K, NestedMap<K>> data;
    Object object; // object to resort to if reached the end of "map-chain"
    ...
}
```

This makes the nesting a bit less messy.